# Object not touching ground when moving platform is falling in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity to make my character jump from a moving platform where it goes up & down infinitely. The problem I'm facing is when the moving platform goes up, the jump is working perfectly but when the platform is going down, my character can't jump most often & I can see the platform is "vibrating" a bit which is weird.

Here are my codes:

**Moving Platform Script [NB - Rigidbody2D is set to Kinematic]**

```
public class Moveground : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform posTop, posBot;
    private float maxTop = -0.5f;
    private float maxBot = -5.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private Transform startPos;
    private Vector2 nextPos;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        nextPos = startPos.position;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (transform.position == posTop.position)
        {
            nextPos = posBot.position;
        }

        if (transform.position == posBot.position)
        {
            nextPos = posTop.position;
        }
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPos, speed*Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

**PlayerController.cs (Only Jump part)**

```
[SerializeField] private LayerMask ground;
private Collider2D coll;

private void Start()
{
    coll = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    InputManager();
}

private void InputManager()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && coll.IsTouchingLayers(ground))  // Moving Platform's layer is also "ground"
    {
        Jump();
    }
}

private void Jump() {
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpforce);  // jumpforce is a float number
}
```

How can I resolve this issue? I'm new to Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "IsTouchingLayers" try something like this in the PlayerController class:

```
public bool IsGrounded()
{
    return Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 0.1f, ground);
}
```

and play around with the distance argument, which is the 0.1f one.

If your player transform is not at the bottom of the player, you can also put in something like this instead of 0.1f:

```
coll.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f
```

Comment: Thank you! This solves the jumping issue but the platform is still shaking. It's not important but if you've any idea of fixing this then please let me know.

Comment: Try using Update instead of FixedUpdate. You are using Time.deltaTime in FixedUpdate, which defeats its purpose. FixedUpdate is called a fixed number of times per second, which is why it's used for things that need to happen the exact same amount of times per second, regardless of the framerate, like physics. But most of the time you should just use Update in combination with Time.deltaTime to get frame independence.